# How to combine FontWeight option with Text[]?

Tags: graphics, style, text

Does anyone know how to combine the FontWeight option with Text[] items in Mathematica? It works fine with Style[], according the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FontWeight.html). However when I feed this to Text[] (to then feed into the Graphics[] function), the weighting disappears and only assumes one of two weights.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like

```
Text[Style["some text", FontWeight -> weight]]
```

See this example from the documentation of `Text`:

```
Graphics[{Text[Style["ABCDEF", Large, Bold, Red], {0, 0}, 
   Automatic, {2, 1}], Circle[]}]
```

which produces
[image: Bold text using FontWeight]

The documentation of `Bold` says:

```
Bold is effectively equivalent to FontWeight->Bold
```

**Edit** This might indeed be a bug. Even if the system supports multiple font weights, in Graphics there really only seem two to be available.

```
weights = {"Thin", "Light", "Plain", "Medium", "SemiBold", "Heavy", "Black", "Fat"};

Row@Table[Style["A", Large, FontWeight -> w], {w, weights}]
```

[image]

```
Row@Table[ImageCrop@Graphics[#]&@Text@Style["A", Large, FontWeight->w], {w,weights}]
```

[image]

Comment: that doesn't work though. If you try to feed "Heavy", "Black", or "Fat", these are all identical to entering a Fontweight-> "Bold", as I could have elaborated a bit more on in the original question. I need heavier weights, but thank you anyways

Comment: @Wai-GaDHo From the docs: "Standard settings are Plain and Bold. For **some fonts and on some computer systems**, additional settings are supported, such as [...] "Heavy", "Black", and "Fat"". You are probably trying to use a font combination that does not support those attributes.